# In Vs2013 with resharper, what are the yellow lines on the left margin

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

In Vs2013 with Resharper, what are the yellow lines on the left margin.

This ought to be an easy question to answer, but I wasn't able to guess the keywords to search.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coloured marks in the border are how Visual Studio tracks changes (not related to ReSharper). The yellow marks indicate that the line has changes but not yet been saved, they will turn green once saved or orange if saved and then undone, according to [this link](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2018/04/what-the-colors-mean.aspx)

Comment: Thanks man, I figured it was something simple, I appreciate your help!